# Remove several rows from dataframe using search

Tags: r

I have the following dataset `mydf` from which I extract several rows (in this example I extract 2 rows)

```
library(dplyr)


mydf<- data.frame(c(1,1,3,4,5,6),
                  c(22,22,3,10,20,30),
                  c(2,10,20,20,15,10),
                  c(3,10,20,20,15,10),
                  c(4,10,20,20,15,10),
                  c(5,10,20,20,15,10))
colnames(mydf)<-c( "ID1","ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6")

asd <- (mydf %>% group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% filter(n()==2))
```

I would like to **remove** the rows contained in `asd` from `mydf`. Generally, this can be done by

```
mydf[-c(2, 4, 6), ]
```

where in this example we remove row number 2, 4 and 6.

However, in my case I don't know beforehand what row-numbers in `mydf` the rows in `asd` have. So that means we have to search for them first.

What is the easiest way to do this in R, if my data is too large to use a `for`-loop?

Comment: Just use `anti_join(mydf, asd)`  to remove those rows or use `mydf %>% group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% filter(n()!=2)` to get the subset right away.

Comment: anti_join also works - different strokes for different folks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dplyr has the following function which removes rows in the first data frame that are also in the second:

```
setdiff(mydf, asd)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `base R`

```
mydf[!as.character(interaction(mydf)) %in% as.character(interaction(asd)),]
```